# How to forward packets via C# to another TCPClient running on another port

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, vnc

How can I forward packets using C# to another TCPClient running on another port.

I am new to Sockets programming in .Net. I am trying to make a VNC Repeater much like this perl script: http://snipt.org/wonG but I cannot keep my stream continuous.

An example of what I want to achieve is this:

Port 5500 listens, inspects the packet RemoteEndPoint and then and sends the packet back out on Port 5901.

Because the bulk of the traffic is considered 1 big open stream (it does not close or send chunks of data, it sends traffic for upwards of 10 minutes) how can I do this?

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how to execute a TCPClient packet forwarding solution that supports large open streams(sessions)?

Comment: A TCP stream is the same no matter how it is used.  Just loop, calling Read() and Write() back out whatever you get until the socket is closed.

Comment: Could you possibly post an example link? I should probably stop trying to tinker and get my head around how .Net handles sockets first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://tcpsoftrouter.codeplex.com/ Is a good example.

EDIT: Since this time I have written NRepeat. Available here https://github.com/jeremychild/NRepeat

Comment: GNU3 :-(. Don't even want to open it... If there is a basic part of it you would feel comfortable posting here it would be great.

Comment: Sorry but .net developers have a tendency to NOT share their source code with the community. GNU3 attempts to enforce that people use this for the greater good instead of financial reasons. Just shoot me an email and I will formally allow MIT licence for you or your firm.

Comment: Thank you for your repo, I have learned from it :)